# Removing part of a string in a query string in a URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an input URL that looks something like this:

```
http://localhost/20north/Numark/product/1/B$@!00$@!4JPPO94$@!
```

While redirecting this to a new URL, I need to find and remove all occurrences of "$@!" from the last part of the url, so that it becomes:

```
http://localhost/20north/Numark/product/1/B004JPPO94
```

**Note:** The last part can be anything and not just `B$@!00$@!4JPPO94$@!`. Also, the position of `$@!` can be anywhere in that last part.

Answer (score 3):

Using mod_rewrite, you just need this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\$@!(.*)$ $1$2 [N]
```

Edit:

Actually, there seems to be a problem when the `$@!` is at the end of the URI. Adding an extra rule to remove the trailing match seems to fix it:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\$@!$ $1
RewriteRule ^(.*)\$@!(.*)$ $1$2 [N]
```

Not quite sure why that was happening.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using php, you could do the following:

```
<?php 
    $this_url = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    if( strpos($this_url, '$@!') !== false ) 
       die(header('Location: ' . str_replace('$@!', '', $this_url))); 
?>
```

Edit: updated the code to become dynamic

Comment: Thanks but we are not using php....apache modules...i am also now adding this to the questions. Thanks anyways